# Laravel multiple files on multiple items

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the Laravel Collective to build a form that contains multiple products, each one with multiple images. When I try to get the images, only the first upladed image comes via request:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('product[0][images]') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  {!! Form::label('product[0][images]', 'Images *', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) !!}
  <div class="col-md-6">
    {!! Form::file('product[0][images]', array('multiple' => true, 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}                        
    @if ($errors->has('product[0][images]'))
      <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('product[0][images]') }}</strong>
      </span>
    @endif
  </div>                        
</div>

// Controller
$inputs = $request->all();
var_dump($inputs);
die;
```

Result:

> array(10) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "qax8yTQ8BTqPTME3bxh64U8CzZr1M2c6hzPk4Ijr" ["product"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["images"]=> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#30 (7) { ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> bool(false) ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(12) **"image1.jpg"** ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(75336) ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(0) ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php3422.tmp" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(11) "php3422.tmp" } } } }

I tried using:

- product[0][images]
- product[0].images[]
- product[0][images[]]

with no success. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

View:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=> array('/pictures-all-tour', $id), 'method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true)) !!}
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
          {!! Form::file('images[]', array('multiple'=>true,'class'=>'send-btn')) !!}
         </div>
        </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary publishtourbutt2">
                Save Photos
            </button>

        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

> Controller:

```
public function picturesalltour($id)
    {


    $files = Input::file('images');
    $file_count = count($files);

    $destinationPath = public_path().'/img/';

    $uploadcount = 0;

    foreach($files as $file) {
      $rules = array('file' => 'required');

        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension;
        $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
        Image::make($destinationPath.$fileName)->fit(1200, 800)->save($destinationPath.$fileName);     

        $uploadcount ++;
        $newpic = 'pic'.$uploadcount;

        DB::table('tours')->where('id', $id)->update([
            $newpic => $fileName
            ]);

        DB::table('photos')->insert([
            'tourid' => $id,
            'userid' => Auth::user()->id,
            'picname' => $fileName
            ]);

    }


    \Session::flash('flash_message', "Pictures successfully added.");

    if($uploadcount == $file_count){
      return redirect('/photos-tour-get/'.$id);
    } 
    else {
      return redirect('/');
    }

    }
```

> Dont know for your case, but i used it like this and it works perfectly, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I should use

```
{!! Form::file('products[0][images][]', array('multiple' => true, 'class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```